# What happened to Daenerys' khalasar?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

An important part of the journey of Daenerys, is the remnants of the khalasar of Khal Drogo. She leads them through the Red Wastes to Qarth, boards the frightened Dothraki onto ships and sails for Astapor. Following this however, the mentions of the Dothraki become few and far between, both in the novels and the TV show.

We know the fates of Irri and Doreah, but what of Jhiqui? I saw some Dothraki briefly in the TV show, guarding the tent of Daenerys, when meeting the Second Sons in 4.3 or 4.2?

So my question is, who and how many of Daenerys' old khalasar are left? Are they integrated into her court? Do they serve with the Unsullied?

Comment: If I remember correctly there were only several hundred left, mostly women, children and young boys (almost exclusively blood relatives of the Khal Drogo). All others went their own ways with their new leaders. Those who stayed are either personal guard/staff or part of the court. But that's books. Don't watch the series. BTW.: clarify if you're asking about show or books.

Comment: I was asking about both the Show and the Books. As evidenced by my reference to both sets of media. I'm interested in differences between the two as well.

Comment: @AcePL in the show it was several dozen at most. They kind of disappeared from the screen

Comment: See also - same question over at the movies & TV site - http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34404/what-happened-to-the-dothraki-loyal-to-daenerys?s=0|1.1596

Comment: An interesting answer, but only half the question. What about the novel universe?

Comment: Daenerys's personal Dothraki bodyguard was slain in Qarth when her dragons were stolen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### A Game of Thrones (TV Show)

By the time Dany and her group reached the gates of Qarth, there were only a few dozen of them left. Most of the khalasar had left after Drogo's death, and of those who stayed with Dany, many died during the journey through the desert.

Once in Qarth, nearly all of the remaining Dothraki

> were killed by Xaro Xhoan Daxos's men when they invaded the compound & took the 3 dragons for Pyat Pree.

This event happens at the end of episode S02E06 "[**The Old Gods and the New**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Old_Gods_and_the_New)".

### A Clash of Kings (books)

In the novels, Dany's khalasar is with her during the journey through The Red Waste, and after entering Qarth, those who survived the journey reside with her in Xaro's palace. However, the tragic events of the TV show do not occur, and the khalasar is assumed to still be with her when she sets sail for Pentos. However, the Dothraki are not mentioned again after she arrives at Astapor and purchases the Unsullied.

We do know the fate of some individuals, however. Her handmaiden Irri still travels with Dany and is present at the arena battle in A Dance with Dragons. In the TV show, Irri was among those

> killed in Qarth.

Comment: `If I look back, I am lost`

Answer (score 2):

There is no indication on the show that Dany's Kalashar are killed in the dragon raid , only Irri. In fact a group are with her when they leave at the end of season 2. We see them again on the ship as they come into Astapor. We see them in season 4 though it gets to be hard to tell how many, to end of season 5 there are palace guard Dothraki.

In the books about 100 of Dany's original Kalashar are still around by the end of novel 5.